# Unicorn does not sever database connections properly after new deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn, octopus

I am currently having a problem with database connections after a Capistrano deploy. On the database server it seems like unicorn does not sever the previous connections and it just keeps adding on top of the old ones. I am doing a preload true, and I also have octopus gem installed as well if that matters. I am not too sure who is to blame for this. I have pasted my unicorn config for the part that matters. Any help is appreciated!

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end
  old_pid = "/tmp/unicorn.my_app_name.pid.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_proxy.instance_variable_get(:@shards).each {|k,v| v.clear_reloadable_connections! }
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

  if Process.ppid > 1 # Not the daemon
  child_pid = server.config[:pid].sub(".pid", ".#{worker.nr}.pid")
  File.open(child_pid, "wb") {|f| f << Process.pid }
  end
end
```

[image: 1] "ps aux"

Comment: I set preload app to false and it seems like It is still seeing the same problem which makes me believe octopus might be the problem. I also forgot to mention in the original post that I only have 2 unicorn workers per server.

Comment: New Theory: Each postgres instance is presentative of a connection in the pool so if there is 2 workers at 5 connections in the pool which would translate into 10 connections total. Would be great if someone can confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "New Theory" is correct. 2 workers with 5 connections will result in 10 total.
Answer is here - [Unicorn do not close DB connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661482/unicorn-do-not-close-db-connections)