# Unicorn do not close DB connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, postgresql-9.2

I am using rails 3.2 + unicorn + postgres DB and i have a question - how does unicorn handle DB connections ?

How I understand:

1. unicorn master process forks X child process.
2. each child process setup DB connection– close in before_fork, establish connection in after_fork.
3. we use connection per process(if we use rails DB connection pooling, we create Y(from database.yml) DB connections per process) - i.e. If process is working(It always works until we not kill it) we keep connection opened and every web request use the same connection(that was opened in after_fork).
4. opened connections will be shown in postgres(or any other DB) as idle or active.

Is it correct or I missed something ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes you are right.
If you set "worker_processes 5" in unicorn.conf, and "pool: 4" in database.yml, will be create d 20 connections to database.

Answer (score 3):

i wrote to Eric Wong he is founder of unicorn gem, he confirmed that it's correct.